# Xcode Swift alertView disappears upon entering root controller

Tags: swift, xcode, push-notification, uialertview

I have looked all over and found answers about how to dismiss the push alertView upon entering the apps root controller.  Currently when receiving a push message while not in the app clicking on the push launches app and if no lockout code was set then it displays correctly.  But if the lockout viewController that asks for a access code appears upon clicking on push message, the message automatically dismisses itself.  How do I stop this.  I can not run debugger because I am not getting a log because app has not officially launched.

PM -> Splash -> Home  (okay: alert remains until dismissed)

PM -> Splash -> Lockout -> access code -> Home 
(automatic dismissal not what I want, I want the user to dismiss alert PM)

Has anyone had this problem and how did you go about fixing it

Comment: Could you post some code?

Comment: I'm confused about what's going on here without code. Alerts will queue if more than one are presented at a time and so something else is going on with the way you're making your alerts

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found out what was going on.  I had created a for loop with my animation block and it was calling the for loop over and over which was dismissing my alertView